# Html Agility Pack appending thead tbody tfoot in existing html table

Tags: html-agility-pack

I have been searching google but no result :(. i have a HTML table like below

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>column1</td>
       <td>column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>column1rowtext</td>
       <td>column2rowtext</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>column1rowtext</td>
       <td>column2rowtext</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>column1EndText</td>
       <td>column2EndText</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to add thead, tbody and tfoot like below using "Html Agility Pack"

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>column1</td>
      <td>column2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>column1rowtext</td>
     <td>column2rowtext</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>column1rowtext</td>
     <td>column2rowtext</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
   <tr>
     <td>column1EndText</td>
     <td>column2EndText</td>
   </tr>
 </tfoot>
</table>
```

can someone guide me on how to use html agility pack to modify the existing html table and add more tags.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Html Agility Pack constructs a Read/Write DOM, so you can rebuild it the way you want. Here is a sample code that seems to work:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load("MyTest.htm");

        // get the first TR
        CloneAsParentNode(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table/tr[1]"), "thead");

        // get all remaining TRs but the last
        CloneAsParentNode(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table/tr[position()<last()]"), "tbody");

        // get the first TR (it's also the last, since it's the only one at that level)
        CloneAsParentNode(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table/tr[1]"), "tfoot");


    static HtmlNode CloneAsParentNode(HtmlNodeCollection nodes, string name)
    {
        HtmlNode parent = nodes[0].ParentNode;

        // create a new parent with the given name
        HtmlNode newParent = nodes[0].OwnerDocument.CreateElement(name);

        // insert before the first node in the selection
        parent.InsertBefore(newParent, nodes[0]);

        // clone all sub nodes
        foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            HtmlNode clone = node.CloneNode(true);
            newParent.AppendChild(clone);
        }

        // remove all sub nodes
        foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            parent.RemoveChild(node);
        }
        return newParent;
    }
```