# how to restrict the automatically inserted tbody element into table elements when its come to browser view?

Tags: html, browser

I Need to restrict the automatically adding tbody tag into the table(In browser view).
See my below input html code:-

```
 <html>
 <body>
 Please enter your name:
 <br/>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>hello</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can prevent this action

Because browsers append tbody element automatically while rendering

Still you cant try to remove the element dynamically through `Javascript`.

Comment: Yes its works. By default if html contains tbody. how to resolve it?

Comment: Remove it using jQuery

Comment: Thanks for reply@ Siddhesh Kulkarni. I Found a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870313/html-agility-pack-appending-thead-tbody-tfoot-in-existing-html-table?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

You can't restrict the automatically adding tbody tag action

You can remove explicitly [Please  refer to remove tbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933288/javascript-delete-a-table-tbody-tag)

Comment: Thanks @ Amol. I found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870313/html-agility-pack-appending-thead-tbody-tfoot-in-existing-html-table?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout function:

let tbl = document.getElementById("table_temp_list_foods");

// Get the table
setTimeout(() => {
tbl.innerHTML = ``;
}, 1000);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).